# ruby - passing open file object to function as parameter

Tags: ruby, file, io

Why does this not work in Ruby when reading and writing to files?

```
def write_to_file(a_file)
    a_file.puts("hello")
end

a_file = File.new("test.txt", "w")
write_to_file(a_file)
```

the alternative i have found is to pass the file name to each function that reads or writes from it, and open and close it in that function.

why can't i open the file and pass that open file object to a function? does the `a_file` variable I am assigning not create a file object?

Comment: The code you showed works just fine. Maybe you forgot to close the file so the output is still being buffered? Try `a_file.close` after calling `write_to_file`

Answer (score 2):

`File.new` does create a file but its opened in buffered mode (or non-sync mode), unless filename is a tty. If you want to open a file and write contents to it the idiomatic way is:

```
File.open("test.txt", "w") do |file|
  file.write("hello")
end
```

This ensures that the file is closed when you're finished. That file handler can be passed around however you want:

```
def write_to_file(file)
  file.write("hello")
end

File.open("test.txt", "w") do |file|
  write_to_file(file)
end
```